# VS code does not recognise letters Õ, Ä, Ö, Ü but encoding is UTF-8

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, encoding, utf-8

I have been coding in English so far but now it is necessary to code in my native language which is Estonian. We have letters like Õ, Ä, Ö and Ü but VS code does not seem to like them that much.

Here is an example code and also output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Tegu on sõna äraarvamise mänguga\n"); 
}
```

The output would in my case be:

```
Tegu on s├Ána ├ñraarvamise m├ñnguga
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is more to encoding than just the source file. You need to make sure that your shell/console also uses the right encoding.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but I can tell you that the bad output you're getting looks like the characteristic [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) pattern for UTF-8 being misinterpreted as some unibyte encoding, and that means the problem is with your terminal emulator, _not_ with your code or how it's being compiled.

Comment: I suggest that you pipe the output of your program to a file, and then inspect the file using a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor). You can then see if the output has the proper values. Please post this hexadecimal representation of the output into the question.

Comment: This is a fun, interesting, challenging, occasionally quite difficult problem.  It has three different parts: (1) your C programming and compilation environment, (2) the actual C code you write, and (3) the OS execution environment in which your compiled code actually runs.  For UTF-8 encoding specifically, there are usually no problems with (2).  And it looks like your programming environment in (1) is letting you enter multinational UTF-8 characters into your C code just fine.  So the problem is somewhere in (3).

Comment: (continued) But problems in (3) can be the trickiest to resolve, because they totally depend on details of your OS and your program's execution environment.  For me (programming in gcc under MacOS) it all just magically works.  Linux is similar.  I gather that things tend to be tricker under Windows, but I can't help you there, because I don't use Windows much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually was a super easy fix for this...

```
    #include <windows.h>
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001); //Set console encoding to utf8
```

Using the next code you can find out what is the encoding of your console and if it is wrong then it can be changed with SetConsoleOutputCP(.....):

```
    #include <windows.h>
    unsigned cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
```

And it needs to be matched - mine was not :)

Comment: So UTF-8 output to the console on Windows is super easy, cool! A small request: when you get to do UTF-8 input from the console, please write Q&A on that too.